# hook differently for different branches

Tags: git

I have a server where my git repository was initiated with the --bare argument.
In the hooks directory, i have a post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/git/sureshots.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/andrepadez/production/sureshots git checkout -f
echo 'branch master deployed to live'
```

I only want the `checkout -f` to occur when i push to the branch
    master.

1. when i push to a different branch, my work_tree isn't updated but i still see the echo of 
   'branch master deployed to live'.
2. I would like to have a different setting for the branch release.

I wish to understand bullet 1, and learn how to do bullet 2.
I've searched through the docs but i can't make sense of it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read off the updated refs from stdin, and then trigger the hook when master is update.  Something like:

```
while read oldrev newrev ref ; do
    if [ "$ref" == "refs/heads/master" ]; then
        GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/andrepadez/production/sureshots git checkout -f
        echo 'branch master deployed to live'
    fi
done
```

**Update:**

Sorry, I didn't notice there was a question there.  The `post-receive` script always runs on any push, but your checkout command is just checking out whatever the current HEAD is supposed to be (which is master).  If you need it to deploy a different branch, then you need to tweak the post-receive script.

A couple of things to keep in mind here.  Git is a version control tool, not a deployment tool.  So while you can do this stuff, it's generally not advisable.  You can make this work a little better by having a deploy branch, force pushing your changes to it (if necessary), and having the script checkout the deploy branch.  That way you don't corrupt master, but still have some control over what gets deployed.

The gitolite docs have some interesting information on using [git as a deployment tool](http://gitolite.com/the-list-and-irc/deploy.html), if you're still convinceid it's right for you.

Comment: cool, thanks. That's a good first step. But why did the script run when i pushed to another branch but the production directory didn't get the changes?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez I updated my answer since it was too long to fit in the comment block. :-)